When i am click on process to checkout then get error undefined ajax login
I have some requirements for customers to log in with an email address and phone number. when I am on the back side Store =>Configuration=>Sales=>Checkout=>
Checkout Options=>Allow Guest Checkout set no
when guests log in with the frontend side and add a product to the cart after clicking on process checkout then show a message in a network (undefinedajaxlogin/ajax/login). so please give me a proper solution. I will share my screenshot below when I get errors.

so please give me proper solutions.
